# Is there a way to find the LEAST similar records using Elasticsearch (or "More Unlike This")

Tags: elasticsearch, survey, morelikethis

I have an index full of submissions from a survey form. For any given record I'm trying to find the other records which are *least* like the base record. Eventually it might be great to find the records which are not 100% unlike the source record but *mostly*.

As background, the ultimate goal is that we're trying to pair up survey respondents with people unlike them but not *so* unlike them that a conversation is impossible.

I had considered simply doing a basic More Like This query and then reverse-sorting the results, although I believe that might still find me records which are more similar than not.

Thanks for any suggestions. If there are non-Elasticsearch solutions that are obvious, that's acceptable as well.

Comment: I don't think so there is such a feature in elastic. In any case would you have any sample documents which I can make use as a test data? See if I can find something. That'd be helpful.

Comment: @OpsterESNinja-Kamal - Thanks for responding. This is survey data with some Personally Identifiable information I'd need to get rid of so I'm going to have to see if I can anonymize a set of data and will update this.